# Need to extract the attribute values from left to right which is seperated by delimiters

Tags: mysql

From the below table, I need to extract the 'via' attribute values. I am trying to get the `route_id` using this query:

```
SELECT route_id FROM route_details
WHERE( 
  via LIKE '|%new delhi%|' AND
  via LIKE '|%london%|'
)
```

but in the output I am getting all the rows while I need to get only `route_id` 1 and 2. I don't want `route_id` 3 and 4 in my output.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

```
________________________________________________________________
route_id | via                                                 |
______________________________________________________________
1        |     |newdelhi|dubey|paris|london|                   |
______________________________________________________________
2        |     |new delhi|dubey|paris|london|new york|        |
_______________________________________________________ _____
3        |     |london|paris|dubey|new delhi|                |
_____________________________________________________________
4        |     |new york|london|paris|dubey|new delhi|       |
______________________________________________________________
```

Comment: combine the two likes into one: like '|%new delhi%|%london%|'

Comment: Hello, Jaywalker anti-pattern! Normalize your table with adding new related table to store corresponding route points.

Comment: On what terms should the script know, that you need only id 1 and 2? Meaning, should `new delhi` be before `london` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need `new delhi` to be before `london`.

Try this (after removing all unnecessary characters from the query):

```
SELECT route_id
FROM route_details
WHERE via LIKE '%new delhi%london%'
```